# Find all integers $x$ such that $16x ≡ 26 \text{ (mod }42)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find all integers $x$ such that $16x ≡ 26 \text{ (mod }42)$.

I tried the Euclidian algorithm to try to solve like this:

$42 = 16\times 2 +10$

$16 = 10\times 1 + 6$

$6 = 6 \times 1 + 0$

Is this right or something missing?

Comment: Your third line should start $10=$. Having said that, the approach of finding the gcd of 42 and 16 may or may not get you to the answer you want.  There certainly is more work to be done to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be easier that way:

$16x\equiv26 \pmod {42}$

$8x\equiv13 \pmod {21}$

$x\equiv \frac{13}{8}\equiv \frac{-8}{8}\equiv-1\equiv20 \pmod {21}$

so $x=20+21\text{k}$ with $\text{k}$ integral

Comment: Thank you for that you took your time to answer my questions Evariste!